# How to Mint a NFT which belongs to certain collection in Anchor tests

Tags: anchor, spl-token, nft, anchor-lang

Is there an easy way to mint some fake NFT that belongs to certain fake collection within Anchor JS tests? This would be really handy for testing Anchor instructions, NFTs validation/authentication etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the `@metaplex-foundation/js` package to create them easily.

```
import { keypairIdentity, Metaplex } from '@metaplex-foundation/js`

const metaplex = new Metaplex(provider.connection).use(keypairIdentity(provider.wallet.payer));

const nft = await metaplex.nfts().create({
  name: "My Digital Collectible",
  sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
  uri: "https://arweave.net/my-content-hash",
  isMutable: true,
});
```